# Migration path to Blender.SE

Tags: feature-request, migration

What needs to be done to set up a migration path to the [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)?

The site is still in public beta, but seems to be growing quite well day by day. Does the site need to be out of beta before a migration path can be made?

I have noticed a few new questions that might be sutiable for migration, but there is no option to do so.

Comment: Note that we generally don't migrate old questions to new sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pre-defined migration paths are set up based on how common manual migrations are to the other site.

Remember, you can always flag as "other" with the comment telling where you think the question should be migrated to.