# Can we expand our migration options?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

There's an option in the flagging menu for "this question belongs to a different StackExchange site" where you can choose in which SE the question should be migrated to.

Currently you can only choose StackOverflow, but there are many more SE sites questions can belong to:

- Computer Graphics for graphics related questions
- Computer Science for algorithms not specifically related to gamedev
- Software Recommendations
- Super User for software problems
- Blender for modelling problems
- Artificial intelligence

And there's much more I forgot about. Could we include these too?

Comment: _"Currently you can only choose stack overflow"_ Are you certain? From what I see now, the only _migration path_ that exists is to here, meta. The option about SO is a 'close' option.

Comment: @Alexandre Strange, I thought you could choose that

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285467/a-proposed-philosophy-of-question-migration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no. As for the long answer:

First off, I don't see a historical trend towards frequent migration to any of those sites. We don't migrate much of anything. Occasionally we send a question to Arqade, and prior to our tentative relaxation on the rules around general programming questions we'd send stuff to StackOverflow. But since that relaxation that's mostly dried up. [Our migration rate is 0.46%](http://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/query/552122/migration-rate) as I write this.

Even if I agreed that we should have the migration paths you are proposing (and I don't), there doesn't seem to be sufficient evidence to convince StackExchange of that. They tend only to enable direct migration paths when the frequency of migration is creating a burden for the source site. That is not happening.

Second, migration is a disruption, so we *should* only be doing it rarely. It's historically poorly understood, which is why migration paths are not available to all users by default. Generally we only migrate a question when it's well-formed but blatantly off-topic here, and also blatantly on-topic somewhere else. If it's a junk question it gets closed, if it's on-topic here, it doesn't matter if it's on-topic somewhere else too. It stays here (especially if it's been answered).

Comment: What should we do instead then when requesting a migration to a non-listed SE site?

Comment: @Pikalek Flag for moderator attention, explain why you think it should be migrated.

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1178/40264) answer from Noctrine,

> The pre-defined migration paths are set up based on how common manual migrations are to the other site.
>
> Remember, you can always flag as "other" with the comment telling where you think the question should be migrated to.

I'd advance that even though I see some questions that could be migrated, it's very rare that I see any that could be migrated verbatim. Often they don't fit exactly on the other site, either because of the format, or the content. And since we don't want to be polluted by questions migrated from other sites, I guess it's rare that we actually migrate questions on the other sites.